# cakephp 2.6 controller test case throwing MissingActionException on duplicate testAction()-call

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, exception, controller, phpunit

I hope anyone can help me out with my testing environment.

**my setup**

I am implementing unit tests based on phpunit 3.7.22 with the cake release 2.6.9. Running on ubuntu 12.04 LTS with PHP 5.4.43-1 and postgresql 9.1.

I immplemented controller tests mocking cakes Auth Component to have a user in the session, since my tests depent on that. My controllers return json results, since its an API for a JS-based frontend. I call my controller methods using the *testAction()* call of a generated controller.

```
<?php
App::uses('RequesttypesController', 'Svc.Controller');

class RequesttypesWithResultControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase
{

    public $fixtures = array(
        'app.requesttype',
        'app.user',
        'app.privilege',
        'app.groupsprivilege',
        'app.groupsuser',
        'app.groupscompany',
        'app.company',
    );

    /**
     * Mock the requesttype object so that it can return results depending on the desired outcome
     * 
     * @see CakeTestCase::setUp()
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();    
        $this->controller = $this->generate('Svc.Requesttypes', array(
            'models' => array(
                'Requesttype'
            ),
            'components' => array(
                'Auth' => array(
                    'user'
                ),
                'Session',
                'RequestHandler'
            )
        ));

        $this->controller->Auth->staticExpects($this->any())
        ->method('user')
        ->will($this->returnValue(array(
            'id' => 123,
            'username' => 'myTestUser',
            'company' => 'myTestCompany',
            'usertype_id' => '456',
        ))
        );
        $authResult = $this->controller->Auth->user();
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();
        unset($this->controller);
    }

    /**
     * A logged in user produces a number of requesttypes
     */
    public function testLoggedInUser()
    {
        $result = $this->testAction('/svc/requesttypes/getMyRequesttypes', array('return' => 'vars'));
        $this->assertNotEmpty($this->vars, 'Did not receive webservice response');
        $this->assertTrue(isset($this->vars['data']['code']), 'Received invalid webservice response');
        $this->assertEqual($this->vars['data']['code'], SvcAppController::RESPONSE_CODE_SUCCESS);
    }

}
?>
```

This test passes without errors. Now I want to test my controller-action with different setups, for example users with a different usertype, from a different company, and so on. If I now create a second test-method in my *RequesttypesWithResultControllerTest*-class, calling the same *testAction*-url, i get a *MissingActionException* saying:

```
"Action RequesttypesController::() could not be found."
```

It seems that the testAction calls an empty controller-action, even if the action-url is passed as a parameter. I tried reinitializing the controller by nulling it and calling *$this->generate()* again, but this does not help either.

Of course I can help myself out by creating an own test-controller for every test ending up in a bunch of duplicate test-code, but this somehow seems not right to me.

Am I misusing the test-environment or how can this exception be explained? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for sharing my headache!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further code debugging we finally found the error. We accidently changed the *require* statement of the last line of the */Config/routes.php* file to a *require_once* because of some "Class already defined Exceptions" thrown in the test-environment.

**Wrong routes.php:**

```
require_once CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

For the application itself that made no difference, since the routes are only needed to be initialized once per request. But in a test-environment, the routes are reinitialized several times, which was not possible anymore with the *require_once* include.

This is how the line is supposed to look like, which it does by default:

**Correct routes.php:**

```
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```